# Java input 'cluttered' .txt file into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

so for one of the parts of my assignement, I have to input a cluttered txt file into a bi-dimensional array.

The input is:

```
WWWSWWWW\n
WWW_WWWW\n
W___WWWW\n
__WWWWWW\n
W______W\n
WWWWWWEW\n
```

The problem is that I can't get it to work, it gives me some weird errors that I can't seem to fix, like these:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Here's the code that I have so far, any help would be appreciated! :D

```
public class Main{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
    int numRows, numColumns;
    char mazeArray[][];
    String strings;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("D:/trabalho/maze.txt"));
    numRows = scan.nextInt();
    numColumns = scan.nextInt();
    mazeArray = new char[numRows][numColumns];


    for(int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
     {
        strings = scan.next();

        for(int column = 0; column < numColumns; column++)
        {
            mazeArray[row][column] = strings.charAt(column);
            System.out.print(mazeArray[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
 }

}
```

And basically I'd like to print exactly what the input was like, so the printed output must be:

```
WWWSWWWW\n
WWW_WWWW\n
W___WWWW\n
__WWWWWW\n
W______W\n
WWWWWWEW\n
```

Comment: does the text file also contain the maze size as integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking the Scanner to read `int`s from a file that does not contain `int`s.